# How to get the base datatypes of a structure in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

In gdb is there any way to get base data types of a structure ?

suppose for following structure

```
typedef struct _trial
{
        int i;
        double j;
}trial_t;
```

in gdb

```
(gdb) whatis trial_t
type = struct _trial
(gdb) whatis _trial
No symbol "_trial" in current context.
(gdb)
```

any workarounds ?

I know this works for simple typedefs

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE; 
BYTE var;  
(gdb)whatis var 
type = BYTE 
(gdb)whatis BYTE 
BYTE = unsigned char
```

Comment: By the way, just like `gdb` told you, the type is `struct _trial`, not `_trial`, hence the `No symbol "_trial"...` message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `ptype`

> ptype accepts the same arguments as whatis, but prints a detailed
>   description of the type, instead of just the name of the type.

```
(gdb) ptype struct _trial
```

Or even:

```
(gdb) ptype trial_t
```

> Contrary to whatis, ptype always unrolls any typedefs in its argument
>   declaration

Comment: Good answer. But `struct trial_t` doesn't name a type, you want `ptype trial_t`.